# How to let android accept the square root in edittext?

Tags: java, android

I have an EditText and I want users to be able to enter a number preceded of a square root. Like √5. I already know how to let users enter square root but I want android to be able to read it because I have a method Double.parseDouble to the String of EditText and when I use it with square root android crashes. I think there is a way with String split but it's a lot tiring because if the value is dependent of two editText or more it's pain.
Here is a simple example of what I nearly want to achieve.

```
A= Double.parseDouble(Ainput.getText().toString());
B= Double.parseDouble(Ainput.getText().toString());
double C = A+B;
```

I want C to be the sum of two square roots A & B. How do I proceed and thanks for answering.

Comment: I don't get it. Do you want to square root a user input value or do you want the user to be able to enter the square root symbol as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want android to be able to read it because I have a method Double.parseDouble to the String of EditText and when I use it with square root android crashes

`parseDouble()` does not parse mathematical expressions. It parses `double` values represented as strings.

> I think there is a way with String split but it's a lot tiring because if the value is dependent of two editText or more it's pain

I suspect that you are going to be very disappointed with computer programming.

Your options are:

- Remove the square-root symbol from the text before parsing it, and [use `Math.sqrt()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt(double)) to compute the square root
- Do not have the square-root symbol in the `EditText` at all (e.g., have it in a `TextView` that is immediately to the side of the `EditText`), and [use `Math.sqrt()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt(double)) to compute the square root
- Find a Java mathematical-expression library that works on Android, and see if it will accept your string with the square-root symbol

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the first option?

Comment: @RtsAyat: That would be the `split()` approach that you disliked. Or, use a regular expression or something to try to filter out the square-root symbol. Personally, I would not use that option.

Comment: What option would you use?

Comment: @RtsAyat: That depends a bit on the long-term plan for your app. If your objective is to create an expression-evaluating app (e.g., a scientific calculator), then I would find a Java mathematical-expression library that works on Android, and see if it will accept your string with the square-root symbol. If, OTOH, this is just some square-root-calculating activity, I would keep the square-root symbol out of the `EditText`.